# boost::any_cast to my custom class

Tags: c++, boost-any

I'm new to some boost feature and I'm facing some issues trying to cast a reference to boost::any to a reference to a custom class (for now it's empty, I'm still figuring out the content of the class).

Shortly, I have:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
private:
}

MyClass function(boost::any &source)
{
    if (source.type() == typeid(MyClass))
        return boost::any_cast<MyClass>(source);
}
```

I've not implemented yet the constructors and destructor, so they're still the default ones.

While compiling (in Visual Studio 2017) I get the following message:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall MyClass::~MyClass(void)" (??1MyClass@@$$FQAE@XZ) NativeToManagedBridge   C:\bridge_library\testCli_sources\NativeToManagedBridge\anyHelper.obj   1

Comment: Do you have a definition of constructor and destructor somewhere? If not, try appending `= default` to both declarations.

Comment: The whole `any_cast` business is a red herring, really.

Comment: @StoryTeller what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You have **declared** your default constructor and destructor with `MyClass();` and `~MyClass();` respectively. What does this mean? You are telling the constructor; *"please don't implement a constructor or destructor for me, I will do it"*. If now, you don't **define** them, you will get the linker error you are seeing, because the compiler does not know where to find the definition of your destructor. You can solve this in multiple ways:

1. Explicitly tell the constructor to use the default definition: `MyClass() = default`.
2. Don't list the constructor declaration to allow the compiler to define it automatically.
3. Define your constructor: `MyClass() {}`.

You can read more about [**definition** and **declaration** here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Comment: While with the constructor the problem is easy solved, with the destructor I cannot use the way at point 3. Is there a specific reason why that can't be done? I've always written constructor and destructor at the time I needed, and it's new to me this issue.

Comment: @XectX Destructor can be approached in the same 3 ways. There is nothing different about the definition here for a destructor.